# Sort an object by the property in form of string

Tags: c#, sorting

Is there any way I can make this work. The portion that isn't working is bolded. Essentially, I am trying to figure out a way to get it to sort by the sortColumn which is passed as a string. It wants o => o.Field not o.String.

```
internal List<Apps> GetAllApps(string sortColumn)
{
    List<Apps> employeeList = new List<Apps>();

    // Some database operations that fill employeeList
    // with a bunch of objects from a database operations

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn))
    {
        employeeList.OrderBy(o => **o.sortColumn** ).ToList();

    }

    return employeeList;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var sortPropertyInfo = typeof(Apps).GetProperty(sortColumn);

employeeList
    .OrderBy(o => sortPropertyInfo.GetValue(o, null))
    .ToList();
```

Some sanity checks can be added. Alternatively, consider using [Dynamic LINQ](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I'd really want to have `typeof(Apps).GetProperty(sortColumn)` obtained first and then captured by the function. `GetProperty` isn't the cheapest method, so I don't think it'd be premature optimisation to avoid calling it once for each item.

Comment: Thanks for the dyanmic linq suggestion, and thanks everyone else. All suggestions worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection

```
employeeList.OrderBy(o => typeof(Apps).GetMethod(sortColumn).Invoke(o, null) ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This was the first method I attempted throughout my troubleshooting process. However, it did not work the way I had it written.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx):

```
internal List<Apps> GetAllApps(string sortColumn)
{
    List<Apps> employeeList = new List<Apps>();
    ...
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn))
    {
        employeeList = employeeList.AsQueryable<Apps>()
                                   .OrderBy(sortColumn)
                                   .Cast<Apps>()
                                   .ToList();
    }
    return employeeList;
```

}

Comment: I hadn't heard of Dyanmic LINQ before this. It works very well and seems like the easiest route. Thanks for the working example. I'll probably look into learning Dyanamic Linq now.